# How can I download a single Bitcoin block?

Tags: blockchain, blockchain.info, storage

I just started studying bitcoin.

I would like to be able to download a single block from the Bitcoin network.

I referred to the following:
https://blockchain.info/rawblock/0000000000000000000212f7c098effbb7d814b481ead2b315f605371e47bae1?format=hex

But, it's not the size of the block I know (like 1MB).

How can I get one?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's the whole block. The hex text is 2.5 MB. Hex has 50% efficiency, so the block is 1.25 MB.

Since SegWit, blocks can be larger than 1 MB. There's a 4 MB hard limit which is almost impossible to reach. (With the largest block to date being 2.4 MB, [4.8 MB in hex](https://blockchain.info/rawblock/0000000000000000000d5082f38c5b155a49c2208156b94ce9a0d4ce001f5ead?format=hex))

Comment: Thanks!! Now I know hex efficiency. So can i get original data size in python (1.25MB)?

Comment: You're welcome. More precisely, two hex characters code for one byte  @seongukpark

Comment: I'm so sorry.. This is the last question. Can I get original size data? (Change two hex characters code to one byte in python)

Comment: You need to decode hex to have binary data: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5682984